# Extract example from python help into ipython session

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ipython, manpage

In `ipython` I can run something such as

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.join?
```

and view help for `DataFrame`.

At the end of the help file there are often examples, such as

```
Another option to join using the key columns is to use the `on`
parameter. DataFrame.join always uses `other`'s index but we can use
any column in `df`. This method preserves the original DataFrame's
index in the result.

>>> df.join(other.set_index('key'), on='key')
  key   A    B
0  K0  A0   B0
1  K1  A1   B1
2  K2  A2   B2
3  K3  A3  NaN
4  K4  A4  NaN
5  K5  A5  NaN
```

I'm wondering whether there's a quick approach to extracting these examples into the current session so that I may look into them further, or if i have to copy paste (then adjust) the code from the help file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For generic Python examples, copy the example then *just paste it*; IPython is smart enough to understand Python's `>>>` and `...` prefixes, as well as it's own prefix format. See [*Pasting of code starting with Python or IPython prompts*](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#pasting-of-code-starting-with-python-or-ipython-prompts) in the IPython manual.

I'm copying the first two examples from the documentation here:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.DataFrame.join?

In [3]: >>> df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3', 'K4', 'K5'],
   ...: ...                    'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']})

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
  key   A
0  K0  A0
1  K1  A1
2  K2  A2
3  K3  A3
4  K4  A4
5  K5  A5

In [5]: >>> other = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2'],
    ...: ...                       'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']})
```

You can also use the [`%paste` terminal magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.terminal.magics.html#IPython.terminal.magics.TerminalMagics.paste) to have IPython do the same; this command pulls the data straight from your clipboard.

Here I put the 3rd example onto the clipboard:

```
In [6]: %paste
>>> df.set_index('key').join(other.set_index('key'))
## -- End pasted text --
Out[6]:
      A    B
key
K0   A0   B0
K1   A1   B1
K2   A2   B2
K3   A3  NaN
K4   A4  NaN
K5   A5  NaN
```

There is also the [`%cpaste` magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.terminal.magics.html#IPython.terminal.magics.TerminalMagics.cpaste), which presents a prompt for you to paste Python code into. You can do so multiple times (from separate sections, perhaps), until you enter a `--` double dash on a line by itself. This does require you have your examples lined up in another location to copy from, or that you use a clipboard that lets you recall previous entries.

You can also copy just the `df` dataframe output and have Pandas read it from your clipboard, using the [`pandas.read_clipboard()` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html); start copying from the columns line onwards; this is the final dataframe output shown in the documentation:

```
In [7]: pd.DataFrame.join?

In [8]: pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')
Out[8]:
  key   A    B
0  K0  A0   B0
1  K1  A1   B1
2  K2  A2   B2
3  K3  A3  NaN
4  K4  A4  NaN
5  K5  A5  NaN
```

I used `\s\s+` rather than the default `\s+`; it's more robust as it'll let you accept column names with a single space in them.

Comment: Is `\s\s+` meant to be for the `sep` argument? Would `\s{2,}` not also work?

Comment: @cs95: Yes, that's the `sep` argument, which is the first positional argument in the call. `\s{2,}` would work too, yes.